# Weird gdb behavior regarding conditional breakpoint(a && b not equal to b && a)

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I have a small C++ program:

```
// test.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template class vector<int>;
int main()
{
   vector<int> v;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {   
      if (!v.empty())
         cout << v[0] << endl;   //<== Add a cond breakpoint here later

      v.clear();
      for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)
         v.push_back(i);
   }   

   return 0;
}
```

This program is compiled in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with gcc 4.8.4.

```
g++ -g -O0 -o test test.cpp
```

Start the program with gdb, and add a conditional breakpoint on line 13. The condition is **"v.size() == 3 && v[0] == 3"**, as shown below. However, this condition doesn't work as expected. It stops when condition is not met.

```
(gdb) b 13 if v.size() == 3 && v[0] == 3
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400ca1: file test.cpp, line 13.
(gdb) info b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000400ca1 in main() at test.cpp:13
        stop only if v.size() == 3 && v[0] == 3
```

Run the program and an error message is given:

```
...
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:13
13           cout << v[0] << endl;
```

And printing `v.size()` shows it's 1, which is clearly not the condition that breakpoint should stop.

```
(gdb) p v.size()
$1 = 1
```

But if I replace the condition breakpoint with **"v[0] == 3 && v.size() == 3"** everything is fine.

```
(gdb) p v.size()
$2 = 3
```

***What's the problem of the first condition?***

**[Update]**

I upgraded gcc and gdb to 6.1.0 and 7.10 respectively on Ubuntu 14.04(both built from source), but this problem is still there.

> $g++ -v
>
> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.0/lto-wrapper
> Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Configured with: ../gcc-6.1.0/configure
> --prefix=/usr --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --disable-bootstrap --with-system-zlib Thread model: posix gcc version 6.1.0 (GCC)
>
> $gdb -v
>
> GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10

Comment: Can't reproduce with GDB 7.11.1. What version are you using?

Comment: On my system all is working perfect. gcc 6.1.0, gdb 7.10.1.

Comment: I believe it's 7.7 by default on Ubuntu 14.04.3. Just now I upgraded it to 7.10 from this location `http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/`. Rebuilt gdb. Unfortunately, I can observe the same problem.

Comment: Interesting. I updated to gdb 7.10 and gcc 6.1.0. I can still see this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded gdb to 7.11.1(by switching to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTE) and this problem is gone.

And for this gdb version, printing a `std::vector` is naturally supported, which is nice.

```
(gdb) print v
$3 = std::vector of length 3, capacity 4 = {3, 3, 3}
```